# ¿Se puede personalizar el mensaje de error de una propiedad de tipo int?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente modelo

```
public class UpdateViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber, ErrorMessage = "El campo teléfono particular debe ser un número")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo teléfono particular es obligatorio")]
    [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Ingresa un teléfono válido")]
    public int Telefono { get; set; }
}
```

El cual lo renderizo en mi vista de la siguiente forma

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Telefono, new { @class = "validate" })
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Telefono)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Telefono, "", new { @class = "red-text" })
```

Por defecto si es que se ingresa un `string` en vez de un `int` en el `input` me arroja un mensaje de error

> El campo Teléfono debe ser un numero

Pero lo que necesito hacer es personalizar ese mensaje de error que me arroja por el tipo de dato y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.

Comment: no sale ese mensaje que vos escribiste?

Comment: El mensaje de error que escribí es el que aparece, pero necesito que sea otro y no ese. Ese mensaje se gatillo por el tipo de la propiedad, donde es un `int` pero no se de que forma poder manejar o pasar un msj personalizado.